# Chrome Extension - Background/Event JavaScript Not Responding or Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

New to making extensions, I origally was attempting to load cookies but realised my EventPage.js didn't seem to be loading - since a basic console.log("Hello") wasn't loading.

I am loading the extension via Chrome "Load unpacked extensions", where manifest,content and background scripts are.

The code attached below is what I've been using to see if I can even get a console log from the event page. Only the content script loads, even If I press a key and that is logged.

CHROME:58

Any suggestions?

Manifest.SON

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Facebook  Extension  ",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "",
"permissions": ["storage", "webNavigation", "activeTab", "tabs", "cookies",  
"*://*.facebook.com/*"], 

"background": [
{
"scripts": ["event_Page.js"],
"persistent" : false
}
],

"content_scripts": [
{
 "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
"css": ["style.css"],
"js": ["jquery-2.1.0.min.js", "talkToEvent.js"]
}
```

]

talkToEvent.js

```
   console.log("Hello World!s");
   $(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("DOM READY!");
  $(document.documentElement).keydown(function (e) {
    console.log("Key Has Been Pressed!");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({Message: "getTextFile"}, function (response) {
        ;
    })
  })
});
```

event_Page.js

```
     console.log("Atleast reached background.js")
     chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Reached Background.js");
    if (request.Message == "getTextFile") {
        console.log("Entered IF Block");
        $.get("http://localhost:63342/Projects/StackOverflow/ChromeEXT/helloWorld1", function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            // to send back your response  to the current tab
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {fileData: response}, function(response) {
                    ;
                });
            });


        })
    }
    else {
        console.log("Did not receive the response!!!")
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect `manifest.json`.

According [event pages docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) it should be an object, but in your manifest it is an array.

Correct **manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Facebook  Extension  ",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "*://*.facebook.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "event_Page.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.youtube.com/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "style.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery-2.1.0.min.js",
        "talkToEvent.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Also fixed missed comma and close bracket.